# Alternatives for ClipData class for displaying images in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-image

In my `ImageGridActivty`, I allow users to upload multiple photos at a time from their Phone Memory.

For getting **URI**s of each image I use `ClipData` class and the `onSelectFromResult(Intent Data)` method shows how I implemented it.

```
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
private void onSelectFromResult(Intent data) {
    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
    Log.e( "onSelectFromResult: ", String.valueOf(clipData.getItemCount() + image_count));
    if (image_count + clipData.getItemCount() <= 4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
            Uri uri = item.getUri();
            image_count++;
            Log.e("Image Count:from Select ", "" + uri);
            Log.e("Image Count:from select ", "" + image_count);
            Uri temp= Uri.parse(compressImage(String.valueOf(uri)));
            FileArray.add(new File(String.valueOf(temp)));
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
            imageURL.add(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                try {
                    bitmap = modifyOrientation(bitmap, String.valueOf(new File(getPath(uri))));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("modifyOrientation: ","IOException" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bitmapimageURL.add(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            gridImageAdapter = new GridImageAdapter(ImageGridActivity.this, bitmapimageURL, new GridImageAdapter.GridImageCallBack() {
                @Override
                public void delete(int pos) {
                    image_count--;
                    Log.e("Image Count onSelectfromResult :on Delete", "" + image_count);
                    FileArray.remove(pos);

                }
            });
            gridview.setAdapter(gridImageAdapter);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult() overriden method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FROM_GALLERY)
                    onSelectFromResult(data);
        }

}
```

Button for adding the images:

```
button_add_images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private  int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag_first = true;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           i.setType("image/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(i, FROM_GALLERY);

        }
    });
```

On line 3 we have `ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();` I am getting error for `getClipData()` which states:

```
Call requires API level 16(current min in 15): android.content.Intent#getClipData
```

So I found out that it is crashing when Android OS is below Android 4.1.2, so are there any other alternatives for `ClipData` in that place, which has almost the same logic which I intended to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edited: added the onActivityResult() from where the onSelelctFromResult() is called

Comment: Intent to the gallery, `startActivityForResult(i, FROM_GALLERY);` where "i" is an intent object for picking images from external memory

Comment: It is the basic android image picker and not any 3rd party app..

Comment: It is `Intent.ACTION_PICK`

Comment: `Intent#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` was added in api level 18 so you have to change your min api level from 15 to 18

Comment: So, if I change this to 18 what happens if a user having versions older than this api level tries to use my app?

Comment: he will not be able to install your app - its 4.5% of the users - see https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/